# In Pandas, generate DateTime index from Multi-Index with years and weeks

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with columns `saledate` (in DateTime, dytpe `<M8[ns]`) and `price` (dytpe `int64`), such if I plot them like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dfp['saledate'],dfp['price']/1000.0,'.')
ax.set_xlabel('Date of sale')
ax.set_ylabel('Price (1,000 euros)')
```

I get a scatter plot which looks like below.

[image]

Since there are so many points that it is difficult to discern an average trend, I'd like to compute the average sale price per week, and plot that in the same plot. I've tried the following:

```
dfp_week = dfp.groupby([dfp['saledate'].dt.year, dfp['saledate'].dt.week]).mean()
```

If I plot the resulting 'price' column like this

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_week['price'].values/1000.0)
plt.ylabel('Price (1,000 euros)')
```

I can more clearly discern an increasing trend (see below).

[image]

The problem is that I no longer have a time axis to plot this DataSeries in the same plot as the previous figure. The time axis starts like this:

```
                   longitude_4pp  postal_code_4pp     price  rooms  \
saledate saledate                                                    
2014     1              4.873140           1067.5  206250.0    2.5   
         6              4.954779           1102.0  129000.0    3.0   
         26             4.938828           1019.0  327500.0    3.0   
         40             4.896904           1073.0  249000.0    2.0   
         43             4.938828           1019.0  549000.0    5.0
```

How could I convert this Multi-Index with years and weeks back to a single DateTime index that I can plot my per-week-averaged data against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group using `pd.TimeGrouper` you'll keep datetimes in your index.

```
dfp.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. I had to specify `key='saledate', freq='W'` as detailed below.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new index:

```
i = pd.Index(pd.datetime(year, 1, 1) + pd.Timedelta(7 * weeks, unit='d') for year, weeks in df.index)
```

Then set this new index on the DataFrame:

```
df.index = i
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here are the details of how I implemented the solution suggested by piRSquared:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dfp['saledate'],dfp['price']/1000.0,'.')
ax.set_xlabel('Date of sale')
ax.set_ylabel('Price (1,000 euros)')

dfp_week = dfp.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='saledate', freq='W')).mean()
plt.plot_date(dfp_week.index, dfp_week['price']/1000.0)
```

which yields the plot below.

[image]